# how to add phone Number and email to the address book

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an application which adds the first and last name as new contact in the contacts using

```
  #import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>
```

and this is how I added the first and last name:

```
 [self addAccountWithFirstName:self.firstNameField.text lastName:self.lastNameField.text  inAddressBook:addressBook];
```

I want to add the phone number and the email. How to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

```
    CFErrorRef error = NULL; 
NSLog(@"%@", [self description]);
ABAddressBookRef iPhoneAddressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();

ABRecordRef newPerson = ABPersonCreate();
```

ABRecordSetValue(newPerson, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, people.firstname, &error);
    ABRecordSetValue(newPerson, kABPersonLastNameProperty,         people.lastname, &error);

```
ABMutableMultiValueRef multiPhone =         ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);
ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiPhone, people.phone, kABPersonPhoneMainLabel, NULL);
ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiPhone, people.other, kABOtherLabel, NULL);            
ABRecordSetValue(newPerson, kABPersonPhoneProperty, multiPhone,nil);
CFRelease(multiPhone);
    // ... 
    // Set other properties
    // ...
    ABAddressBookAddRecord(iPhoneAddressBook, newPerson, &error);

ABAddressBookSave(iPhoneAddressBook, &error);
    CFRelease(newPerson);
    CFRelease(iPhoneAddressBook);
if (error != NULL) 
{
       CFStringRef errorDesc = CFErrorCopyDescription(error);
   NSLog(@"Contact not saved: %@", errorDesc);
       CFRelease(errorDesc);        
}
```